# Arrays in array

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I create an array with Ruby (on Rails) in this form:

```
[[0,5], [1,5], [3,7]]
```

Edit: 
I know how to define simple array and add some data:

```
posts = Array[] # or Array.new
posts << data.id # e.g. posts[1,2,3,4]
```

BUT i wanna know how to add (push) data to the array that is more complexive like in first array [[],[]].

Try to understand me, please. :)

Comment: `array = [[0,5], [1,5], [3,7]]`. I'm sorry is this a question?

Comment: You should provide more context. Technically, what you've written above is an array literal in the form you're looking for. What are you trying to achieve, and what code have you written so far?

Answer (score 2):

`num = [[0,5], [1,5], [3,7]]` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to resolve your issue. You're looking for an array of arrays. I think you're confused by how an array can be inside an array. You should keep in mind that an array is just an ordered list of objects. So storing in array in each index is not as foreign as a concept as it may seem.

```
A = [] #an empty array
A[0] = [1, 2]
A[1] = 1
A # => [[1,2], 1]
```

If you want to initialize an array with a default value as an array try

```
A = Array.new(2) {Array.new(2){0}} #This creates an array of size 2 with default values of arrays of size 2 with 0 in each entry.

A[0][1] # returns 0
A[0] # returns [0, 0]
A #returns [[0,0], [0,0]]
```